# jQuery .load() function doesn't work on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, html5-video

I have a problem with the .load(); function on my ipad.

```
$(this).bind('ended',function() {
   $('video').load();
});
```

It's a simply function for loading the same content after the Video ends.
Any idea why this function does not work on an iPad?

Comment: Where does this code work? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Safari (web), Chrome (web) and Firefox (web)

Comment: If you want to replay the video,`$('video')[0].play();`

Answer (score 0):

The .load() method loads the video into the  tag. The .play() method starts the currently loaded video. One more thing to keep in mind is this, is the video the right format? The  tag can load quite a few formats but not every browser can handle every format. iOS browser like iPad/iPhone and even Safari on OSX/Windows can play m3u8 playlists encoded with h264/AAC and mp4 encoded with h264/AAC files but will not play webm, vp8 or avi. So you need to keep all of this in mind when building this type of tag. You might want to look into just building the the player with straight Javascript  and supplying multiple  tags and then let the browser determine the video it can play. (I did this at a past job and it is a lot easier than you might think) And I believe that with certain browsers you need to reset the 'play pointer' and tell it to start at position 0

jsfiddle [dot] net/nexxuz/XuLCC/15/
(will not let be post link without code)

And I was able to get this working playing multiple videos too (once one ended played another) (Ad video plus content video) also I was able to get a mid roll video working too. (at x seconds into video play another video and then once that video is done resume the first video)

Comment: yes - video has the right format - everything playing right but only iPad can not execute the .load(); function... I think to reload this video one more time again after the Video ends is not possible on iPad